# WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete

Tags: android, gradle

After upgrading 'Android Gradle plugin' to 3.4.0, I have got a warning message in /app/build.gradle

> WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variantOutput.getPackageApplication(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

I have tried 'android.debug.obsoleteApi=true' in 'gradle.properties' as recommended, then I got this message.

> REASON: Called from: [android project path]/app/build.gradle:31

The code containing line 31 is the code below.

```
android {

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'my_app' }
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
                    newName = newName.replace("-release", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName)
                    def relativeRootDir = output.packageApplication.outputDirectory.toPath().relativize(rootDir.toPath()).toFile()
                    output.outputFileName = new File("$relativeRootDir/", newName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line 31 is

```
def newName = output.outputFile.name
```

Is this part using API 'variantOutput.getPackageApplication()'? What should I do to solve this warning?

Comment: Are you using fabric?

Comment: No, I am not using.

Answer (score 1):

After I have changed 'app/build.gradle' not to use line 31, the warning message disappears.

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            project.ext { appName = 'my_app' }
            def newName = outputFileName
            newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
            newName = newName.replace("-release", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName)
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}" + newName
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still getting that warning on gradle plugin 5.4.1.